# Intellij idea extract parameter object in groovy

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

Extract parameter object is disabled in groovy.

Is there a way to "activate" that feature?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample code.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192966